# Precise Define Change in Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I am in high school, currently writing a paper on linear algebra explaining concepts at a level that other high school students can understand without having taken linear algebra. I need to define a change in basis alongside the equation $A'=BAB^{-1}$ in a precise way without introducing that many linear algebra concepts. I browsed the web and had trouble finding a clear definition. If you could please add the website you found the definition, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a website for you, though one isn't really necessary.

Say the vector space $V$ is finite dimensional.  Let $\beta$ be a basis for $V$.  Let $B^{-1}$ be the matrix whose columns are the elements of $\beta$.  Then $A'$ is the matrix for the linear transformation $T_A$ whose matrix rel the standard basis is $A$, expressed relative to the basis $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you very much!